# Creating a Service Host?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf

I have created a WCF service.And i am trying to call it from another domain.I have enabled the cross domain option.But my doubt i about how to create a service host??

```
!-<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="jsonwcf.Service1"
      CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs"
      Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory%>
```

When i am changing the markup to this.it shows servicehost missing.what should i do??

### service.cs

```
namespace jsonwcf
{

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    [WebInvoke(
   Method = "GET",
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
 )]
    public List<UserDetails> SelectUserDetails()
    {
        pasDataContext db = new pasDataContext();
        List<UserDetails> results = new List<UserDetails>();

        foreach (User u in db.Users)
        {
            results.Add(new UserDetails()
            {
                UserID = u.UserID,

                EmpName = u.EmpName,
                Email = u.EmailID,
                UserName = u.UserName,
                UserRole = u.UserRole,
                Password = u.Password,
                Telephone = u.Telephone

            });
        }
        return results;
    }


    [WebInvoke(
  Method = "POST",
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
)]
    public string ins(string uid, string pwd, string uname, string ename, string tel, string urole, string eid)
    {

        pasDataContext db = new pasDataContext();
        User u = new User();
        u.UserID = uid;
        u.UserName = uname;
        u.UserRole = urole;
        u.Telephone = tel;
        u.Password = pwd;
        u.EmailID = eid;
        u.EmpName = ename;
        db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(u);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        return "inserted successfully";
    }

}
}
```

### iservice.cs

```
namespace jsonwcf
{

 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "JsonpAjaxService")]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]

   List<UserDetails> SelectUserDetails();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,UriTemplate = "Service/ins")]
    string ins(string uid, string pwd, string uname, string ename, string tel, string urole,string eid);
}
[DataContract]
public class UserDetails
{
      [DataMember]

    public string UserID
    {

        get;

        set;

    }

    [DataMember]

    public string Password
    {

        get;

        set;

    }

    [DataMember]

    public string UserName
    {

        get;

        set;

    }

    [DataMember]

    public string Email
    {

        get;

        set;

    }
       [DataMember]
    public string EmpName
    {

        get;

        set;

    }
       [DataMember]
    public string UserRole
    {

        get;

        set;

    }
       [DataMember]
    public string Telephone
    {

        get;

        set;

    }


}
}
```

Comment: _"it shows servicehost missing.what should i do??"_ - paste the exact exception message.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx

Comment: Error Message : C:\Users\fingent\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\jsonwcf\jsonwcf\Service1.svc: ASP.NET runtime error: The required directive 'ServiceHost' is missing.

Answer (score 0):

A `.svc` [should](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contain something along the following:

> ```
> <%@ServiceHost ... %>
> ```

The error says:

> The required directive 'ServiceHost' is missing.

Your `.svc` begins with:

> ```
> !-<%@ ServiceHost ... %>
> ```

Spot the differences.